# how to create scala object from complex Json data?

Tags: json, scala

This is my json data.

```
{
  "fqAccountId": "DUMMY.8351/8351200212366540",
  
  "domainEntityMetadata": {
    "messageTimestamp": "2021-05-12T03:15:01.335Z",
    "modifiedTimestamp": "2021-04-22T14:10:08.741Z",
    "sourceSystem": "",
    "keyPath": [
      "fqAccountId"
    ],
    "jsvCompatibility": [
      "1.0.0"
    ],
    "domainEntityName": "equipment"
  },
  
  "soloAccountId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
  
  "serviceDeviceAssignments": {
    "equipment": [
      {
        "model": "ES2251",
        "equipmentType": "MTA",
        "deviceCapabilities": [],
        "CustomerOwned": "R",
        "serialNumber": "7C8FDEF58D10",
        "lineOfBusinessDetail": [
          {
            "enterpriseCode": "HSD",
            "description": "HSD"
          }
        ],
        "macAddressListings": [
          {
            "name": "CM",
            "macAddress": "56444"
          }
        ],
        "make": "SERCO",
        "currentLocationEntryDate": "2021-04-22T14:10:08.741Z"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

We have to create scala object from the above json data. Then we have to access the values
and have to print it.

Comment: in json4s: https://github.com/json4s/json4s#parsing-json

Comment: You use any JSON library like: **circe**, **uJson**, **play-json**, **jsonitter-scala**, etc.